# Overloading type from parent namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, c++14

This seems to compile correctly:

```
namespace A {
    template<typename T>
    struct S {};

    namespace B {
        using S = S<int>;
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace A::B;
    S s;
}
```

Even though at the line `using S = S<int>`, the first `S` refers to `A::B::S`, whereas the second `S` refers to the template `A::S`.

Is this standard C++?

Comment: Added language-lawyer tag as it seems relevant here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scope of `S` begins at its *point of declaration*, and for a `using` declaration it is after the type-id to which the alias refers (`S<int>`).

So inside of the declaration, the scope of the new `S` has not started yet, and `S` still refers to `A::S`.

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Point_of_declaration.

Comment: The relevant standard text is https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:alias-declaration and https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#3.sentence-3